# Why can't I install this npm project?

Tags: npm

I have virtually no experience with NPM and I'm having some trouble trying to get an [opensource project (brigadehub)](https://github.com/brigadehub/brigadehub#development-installation) up and running locally.

I just installed NPM using macports (I installed the NPM4 port), `cd`'d into the directory for this project, ran `npm install -g brigadehub` and got this error:

```
    │ ... [millions of these packages]
    │
    ├── user-home@2.0.0
    └─┬ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1
      ├─┬ spdx-correct@1.0.2
      │ └── spdx-license-ids@1.2.2
      └── spdx-expression-parse@1.0.4

npm WARN mongoose-schema-to-graphql@2.4.6 requires a peer of graphql@>=0.7.1 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/opt/local/bin/node" "/opt/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "brigadehub"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path /opt/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/opt/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I was not surprised to see the permission error for /opt/local/lib/node_modules - I'm pretty sure that was created by macports under sudo privileges.  So I gave myself ownership of that entire directory:

```
~/sites/codeforbtv.github.com (master)$ sudo chown -R myuser:wheel /opt/local/lib/node_modules
Password:
~/sites/codeforbtv.github.com (master)$ ls -al /opt/local/lib/node_modules
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser   wheel   102 Feb 25 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  201 root     admin  6834 Feb 25 12:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x   27 myuser   wheel   918 Feb 25 12:59 npm
```

I've retried the npm install command under my user and under sudo, but I'm getting the same response and I don't know what it means :/

```
~/sites/codeforbtv.github.com (master)$ npm install -g brigadehub
npm WARN deprecated yarn@0.17.10: It is recommended to install Yarn using the native installation method for your environment. See https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015-node4@2.1.1: Use npmjs.org/babel-preset-env instead, see https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated mongodb@1.3.23: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher
/opt/local/lib
└── (empty)

npm WARN mongoose-schema-to-graphql@2.4.6 requires a peer of graphql@>=0.7.1 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/opt/local/bin/node" "/opt/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "brigadehub"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.3.0
npm ERR! path /opt/local/lib/node_modules/brigadehub/make start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/opt/local/lib/node_modules/brigadehub/make start'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/opt/local/lib/node_modules/brigadehub/make start'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I've confirmed that, indeed there is no directory for brigadehub.

```
~/sites/codeforbtv.github.com (master)$ ls -al /opt/local/lib/node_modules
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser   wheel   102 Feb 25 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  201 root     admin  6834 Feb 25 12:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x   27 myuser   wheel   918 Feb 25 12:59 npm
```

It should be able to create any directories it wants to though.  So what is NPM trying to tell me here?